# XSL stylesheet - for-each displaying data multiple times. How do I fix this?

Tags: xml, xslt

After some help through this website and tutorials I have gotten the hang of parsing and XML document using XSLT. I am having one issue though. I am trying to display this XML data in table with individual columns for each attribute of the player.

```
<bbgame> <- Root
    <team vh="V" id="MSU" name="MISSOURI STATE" record="8-2">
        <linescore line="24,36" score="60">
          <lineprd prd="1" score="24"></lineprd>
          <lineprd prd="2" score="36"></lineprd>
        </linescore>
    <player uni="01" code="01" name="Keith Pickens" checkname="PICKENS,KEITH" gp="1">
          <stats fgm="1" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="15" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="2" tf="0" to="2" dq="0"></stats>
          <statsbyprd prd="1" fgm="0" fga="1" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="0" fta="0" tp="0" blk="0" stl="0" ast="0" min="7" oreb="0" dreb="0" treb="0" pf="2" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
          <statsbyprd prd="2" fgm="1" fga="2" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="8" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="0" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
        </player>
    </team>
</bbgame>
```

I have two teams. Home and Visiting determined by the team - vh = "V" or "H". I have just included one team for brevity. I have written this template-match into my stylesheet. 
xsl:template match="team//player">

```
<xsl:template match="team//player">
    <xsl:for-each select="//player">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px"><xsl:value-of select="@checkname"/></td>
                    <td width="50px"> <xsl:value-of select="@fgm"/> </td>
                    <td> <xsl:value-of select="@fga"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

However the names are being displayed multiple times, 30 sometimes it looks like and the "fga" and "fgm are not displaying at all. Also when I try to call the template using an individual team such as `<xsl:apply-templates select="team[@vh='v']//player"/>` it is not working either.

I am using: `<xsl:apply-templates select="team//player"/>` in the body of my XSL to retrieve this template. All the other ones are functioning correctly but I'm sure this is a syntax or logic error that I can't figure out. Thanks for the help. This website has been a wonderful resource.

EDIT: Added the root to clear up any confusion.

Comment: I am not sure but should I include the HTML? It is quite long due to the multiple outputs of the XML data. I just wasn't sure if it would be useful.

Comment: It would help if you showed just the HTML you would expect for the XML sample you have provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the reason you're getting individual players output multiple times is that your first `<xsl:template match="team//player">` matches all of the `<player>` elements anywhere under `<team>`. For each of these, the `<xsl:for-each select="//player">` matches all of the `<player>` elements anywhere in the XML. So effectively, you're saying "find each player, then for each of those, find each player".

The reason the attributes are not matching is that `@fgm` and `@fga` are attributes of `<stats>`, not `<player>`.

I suspect the reason that `<xsl:apply-templates select="team[@vh='v']//player"/>` is not working is that the value of your `@vh` attribute in your XML is an upper-case 'V'. XPath is case-sensitive.

In my solution, I've modified your input XML example to include two players, as this replicated what I think your problem was (individual players being output more than once).

```
<team vh="V" id="MSU" name="MISSOURI STATE" record="8-2">
  <linescore line="24,36" score="60">
    <lineprd prd="1" score="24"></lineprd>
    <lineprd prd="2" score="36"></lineprd>
  </linescore>
  <player uni="01" code="01" name="Keith Pickens" checkname="PICKENS,KEITH" gp="1">
    <stats fgm="1" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="15" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="2" tf="0" to="2" dq="0"></stats>
    <statsbyprd prd="1" fgm="0" fga="1" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="0" fta="0" tp="0" blk="0" stl="0" ast="0" min="7" oreb="0" dreb="0" treb="0" pf="2" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
    <statsbyprd prd="2" fgm="1" fga="2" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="8" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="0" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
  </player>
  <player uni="01" code="01" name="Robbie Fowler" checkname="FOWLER,ROBBIE" gp="1">
    <stats fgm="1" fga="3" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="15" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="2" tf="0" to="2" dq="0"></stats>
    <statsbyprd prd="1" fgm="0" fga="1" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="0" fta="0" tp="0" blk="0" stl="0" ast="0" min="7" oreb="0" dreb="0" treb="0" pf="2" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
    <statsbyprd prd="2" fgm="1" fga="2" fgm3="0" fga3="0" ftm="2" fta="3" tp="4" blk="1" stl="1" ast="0" min="8" oreb="0" dreb="2" treb="2" pf="0" tf="0" to="1" dq="0"></statsbyprd>
  </player>
</team>
```

In which case the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="team/player">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
    <td width="200px"><xsl:value-of select="@checkname"/></td>
    <td width="50px"> <xsl:value-of select="stats/@fgm"/> </td>
    <td> <xsl:value-of select="stats/@fga"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output HTML:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="200px">PICKENS,KEITH</td>
      <td width="50px">1</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td width="200px">FOWLER,ROBBIE</td>
      <td width="50px">1</td>
      <td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you to both you and Matthew. You have both helped me immensely. I am now seeing the correct code. I had one last question if you or Matthew have time. For some strange reason after the names I am seeing the text Team at the end of each list of players. Is this because of the </team> at the end of each group of players? I'm not sure how to delete this?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your complete XSLT stylesheet and the input XML you are applying it to. I would suggest you provide these in a new question. If possible, try to reduce them to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem (while still being valid).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how the rest of your XSL looks like I can see that the one template you provided suffers from a lack of understanding of context.

What I mean by that is that you are not referencing the elements that you think you are and the fact that you are getting any relevant information is coincidence. Let me explain...

Your template match is looking for `team//player`. This is saying look for any `player` any where under team. If you only have the one player it is fine but if your XML was to look like the below you might be accessing the wrong `player`.

```
<team>
  <player>
    <player/>
  </player>
</team>
```

Depending on what your `apply-templates` call looks like I would change your match to either `team/player` or just simply `player`.

The next issue is your `for-each`. Currently your template is set in the context of `team/player`, as we just covered. However, your `for-each` is set to `//player` which again, because of the double slash, is looking for `player` in any context. You could remove the double slashes but then you would be looking for it in the context of `team/player/player` which doesn't exist. I think at this point you probably don't want a `for-each` because if the template is defined correctly it should be going through all of the `player` elements.

The last part is the attributes in your `value-of`. Again going back to the context of your template you would be looking for attributes at this location `team/player/@fmg` and `team/player/@fga` neither of which exist. You can just update the selects to include the element name `stats/@fmg` or `statsbyprd/@fmg` depending on what element you wanted to get the attributes from.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am looking at your suggestions and my code now. There are 20 players in my XML document, 10 <player> headings under the node <team vh="V"> and 10 under the node <team vh="H">. I was using a for-each loop because I wanted to create two tables, one for each team with all the statistics. Could I accomplish this without using the for-each loop as you mentioned? I thought that just using a value-of would only select the first <player> under each <team> node.